# Webview displying html code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a webview that loads an html file but when testing, the webview only shows the code rather than showing the page.  Any way to fix this?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iphone"
 ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown); 
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the HTML string directly

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString: htmlString baseURL: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[myWebView loadHTMLString: htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];`